# Node.js Q library: chain promise functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

First attempt at using node.js and making a controller. I'm using knex for the queries, and Q library for promises.

I'm trying to chain the async functions that query the DB but end up with an error here:

`this.getPosts().then(this.getTags).then(function() ...`

If I do only `this.getPosts()` or only `this.getTags()`, it correctly fetches them.

The `read` function is from the route.

```
var db = require('../db');
var Q = require("q");

class IndexController {
    constructor(page, data) {
        this.page = page;
        this.data = data;
    }

    getTags(){
        var deferred = new Q.defer();
        db('tags').select().then(function(tags){
            this.data.tags = tags;
            deferred.resolve();
        }.bind(this));
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    getPosts(){
        var deferred = new Q.defer();
        db('posts').select('*', 'posts.id as id', 'tags.name as tag')
        .innerJoin('users', 'posts.user_id', 'users.id')
        .leftJoin('post_tags', 'posts.id', 'post_tags.post_id')
        .leftJoin('tags', 'post_tags.tag_id', 'tags.id')
        .then(function(posts){
            this.data.posts = posts;
            deferred.resolve();
        }.bind(this));
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    read(res){ // <-- FROM ROUTE
        this.getPosts().then(this.getTags).then(function(){
            res.render(this.page, this.data);
        }.bind(this));
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Hi @frosty, what error do you get? And I'm wondering why are you using Q library for promises where you can create a promise using the Promise constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

knex is already using Promise so you don't have to use `q`. Just return it.

```
var db = require('../db');

class IndexController {
    constructor(page, data) {
        this.page = page;
        this.data = data;
    }

    getTags() {
        return knex('tags').select().then(function(tags) {
            this.data.tags = tags;
            return tags
        }
    }

    getPosts() {
        return knex('posts').select('*', 'posts.id as id', 'tags.name as tag')
            .innerJoin('users', 'posts.user_id', 'users.id')
            .leftJoin('post_tags', 'posts.id', 'post_tags.post_id')
            .leftJoin('tags', 'post_tags.tag_id', 'tags.id')
            .then(function(posts) {
                this.data.posts = posts;
                return posts
            }
    }

    read(res) { // <-- FROM ROUTE

    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Do I leave the `read` function the same? I get this error: `Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined [in getTags]`

Comment: you need to use `Promise.bind(this)` before the promise chain in order to use `this` here.